# Are CompletableFutures thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, completable-future, spring-async

I have a thread that invokes two separate threads.  It passes in the same `CompletableFuture` to both of those child threads.  If `.get()` was called in both of those threads at the exact same time, would I get any type of concurrency issues?

- could it corrupt the `CompletableFuture`?
- is it possible that I don’t see the last changes done on the object returned by `.get()`?
- what if I modify that object afterwards?

As a concrete example, in the following code, would it be possible that the two threads print a different value, assuming nothing changes the object returned by `cfInput.get()` after `cfInput` is completed?

```
public void mainClass(CompletableFuture<ObjA> cfInput){
  class1.doAsync1(cfInput);
  class2.doAsync2(cfInput);
}

@Async
public void doAsync1(CompletableFuture<ObjA> cfInput){
  //logic
  System.out.println(cfInput.get().getObjB().getBlah());
  //logic
}

@Async
public void doAsync2(CompletableFuture<ObjA> cfInput){
  //logic
  System.out.println(cfInput.get().getObjB().getBlah());
  //logic
}

public class ObjA{
  private ObjB objB;
  public ObjB getObjB();
  public void setObjB();
}
public class ObjB{
  private String blah;
  public String getBlah();
  public void setBlah();
}
```

Comment: Probably not, this is really vague. The contract of .get() doesn't really require any concurrency issues.

Comment: How is this a vague question? I am simply asking if I will have concurrency issues, if I have two async methods calling .get on the same completable future?

Comment: Agreeing with @matt. It would seem really strange to me if `get()` could not be safely called from more than one thread. It's entirely reasonable to think that more than one thread in some multi-threaded program might need to await the result of a computation or a query, and if you're using `CompletableFuture`, then you are, by definition, doing multi-threaded programming.

Comment: @SolomonSlow  Thanks for the information.  To change the question a bit, would it cause problems if I get the object from the CompletableFuture and grab values from it? Or would it only cause problems if I modify the object in some way?

Comment: @Brian, you mean, the object that is returned by `get()`? But that is _your_ object, right? I mean, it's whatever object your code supplied to complete the future. Your code example doesn't show where that object comes from or even, the type of that object. So unless you show more code, you are the only person who can say whether it's thread-safe or not.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I added some more code to the example.  In my example above, would that cause any issues, if both doAsync1 and doAsync2 tried to print out that value at the exact same time?

Comment: You're not actually asking about `CompletableFuture` anymore. You're asking about the object returned by `get`, which is a custom object and will follow whatever thread safety rules you choose to implement in it. Once `get` returns, you're no longer in `CompletableFuture` territory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## `CompletableFuture` is inherently thread-safe

You could simply assume this from the fact that this class is designed to be used in a multi-threaded context, however this is more clearly specified in [the description of the `java.util.concurrent` package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility):

> ### Memory Consistency Properties
>
> [Chapter 17 of the Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5) defines the *happens-before* relation on memory operations such as reads and writes of shared variables. The results of a write by one thread are guaranteed to be visible to a read by another thread only if the write operation *happens-before* the read operation.
> […]
> The methods of all classes in `java.util.concurrent` and its subpackages extend these guarantees to higher-level synchronization. In particular:
>
> - […]
> - Actions taken by the asynchronous computation represented by a Future *happen-before* actions subsequent to the retrieval of the result via `Future.get()` in another thread.

So this implies that any write that is performed by a thread before it completes a future will be visible to any other thread that calls `get()` on that future (i.e. it “*happened-before*”).

## Your objects are *not* inherently thread-safe

… nor are they “protected” by `CompletableFuture`

Even though `CompletableFuture` itself is thread-safe, and provides some guarantees on the visibility of your writes, it does not make your objects thread-safe.

For instance, if you modify the object returned by `CompletableFuture.get()`, those changes are not guaranteed to be visible to any other thread until you enter another *happens-before* relationship. You may thus need additional synchronization to enforce thread-safety on that object.